# How do check that uninstalling Macports won't break things?

Tags: macports

Its been over a year since I installed Macports for Ruby. I want to uninstall but I can't remember if I was using for anything crucial. Can I get a nice list of ports that was directly installed?

Comment: Do you mean what did macports install - or do you want to also find the executables/scripts you built using macports?

Comment: I guess, "what did macports install?"

Answer (score 1):

[Macports documents](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) how to uninstall it

Uninstall the ports by

```
sudo port -fp uninstall installed
```

Then remove all the files

```
sudo rm -rf \
    /opt/local \
    /Applications/DarwinPorts \
    /Applications/MacPorts \
    /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.* \
    /Library/Receipts/DarwinPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/Receipts/MacPorts*.pkg \
    /Library/StartupItems/DarwinPortsStartup \
    /Library/Tcl/darwinports1.0 \
    /Library/Tcl/macports1.0 \
    ~/.macports
```